# Installing NPM Modules via the Frontend

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I am working on an app wherein I would like to be able to install NPM modules via the frontend. I have no idea, though, how to do so. That is, I know how to do CRUD actions via the front end, but I don't know how to either interact with the command line or run command line functions via the front end.

Are there packages that can help with this or is this built into Node.js somehow?

In short, how can I connect my front-end to my backend in such a way that I can install an NPM package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module. It's built-in so you don't need to install any additional module.

Mostly what you're looking for is either [`spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) or [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

For example, if you want to run `npm install some_module` you can do:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

let command = 'npm install some_module';
let options = { cwd: '/path/to/node/project' };

exec(command, options, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    // Do anything you want with program output here:
    console.log('output:', stdout, stderr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check the documentation for child_process in Node JS:
[Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
   console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

The key difference between exec() and spawn() is how they return the data. As exec() stores all the output in a buffer, it is more memory intensive than spawn(), which streams the output as it comes.

Generally, if you are not expecting large amounts of data to be returned, you can use exec() for simplicity. Good examples of use-cases are creating a folder or getting the status of a file. However, if you are expecting a large amount of output from your command, then you should use spawn()

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to install an npm package via "the front end" is to have node spawn npm as a child process based off of the package name that the client provides.

```
var child = require('child_process').exec(`npm i ${package_name}`);

child.on('exit',function(){

    //npm finished

});
```

This should install the module given that package_name is the name of the npm package, in the same directory that the script is running in. In terms of getting the package name from the front end to the back end, there are several different ways to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Did you mean to write `.exec` in your answer or was that supposed to be `.spawn`?

Comment: no .exec is correct as it's spawning a bash script to initialize npm

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run the your backend application without NPM modules installed, one thing that I think you can do is to make a plain nodejs file without any modules, which will receive the args when invoked, and you can use that args to the required modules, because that file will run with just core modules